# Como deletar todas as collections do MongoDB no Laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb, testes

Uma boa prática em TDD é manter a base de dados limpa entre os testes. Para isso o Laravel utiliza o *Trait* `RefreshDatabase`. Porém, isso ainda não funciona para a base de dados MongoDB.

A minha ideia é deletar todas as collections no método `tearDown` da minha classe de teste.

Como deletar todas as collections?

Eu utilizo a implementação https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é deletar a base de dados no `tearDown`, usando comandos do mongo mesmo, por exemplo

```php
DB::command(['dropDatabase' => 1]);
```

É possível colocar isso em um trait, de modo similar ao `RefreshDatabases`

Ou também:

Há uma issue aberta sobre isso, no repositório do laravel-mongdb, pode ajudar:

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/1475